# Automate the Boring Stuff - Chapter 5 - Chess Dictionary Validator

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

First post, new to programming and having fun! All feedback on this post and my questions are welcome.

I'm working through Automate the Boring Stuff and attacking the first Chapter 5 problem [Chess Dictionary Validator](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter5/).

*In this chapter, we used the dictionary value {'1h': 'bking', '6c': 'wqueen', '2g': 'bbishop', '5h': 'bqueen', '3e': 'wking'} to represent a chess board. Write a function named isValidChessBoard() that takes a dictionary argument and returns True or False depending on if the board is valid.*

*A valid board will have exactly one black king and exactly one white king. Each player can only have at most 16 pieces, at most 8 pawns, and all pieces must be on a valid space from '1a' to '8h'; that is, a piece can’t be on space '9z'. The piece names begin with either a 'w' or 'b' to represent white or black, followed by 'pawn', 'knight', 'bishop', 'rook', 'queen', or 'king'. This function should detect when a bug has resulted in an improper chess board.*

**my questions and code:**

1. Is evaluating dictionary keys/values through these for loops + multiple if statements the "best practice"? It seems like a lot of code. Changing to include some elif caused issues if it followed with another if statement in the for loop.
2. Line 23 `if i[0] == 'b':` errors out because the chess spaces which are empty string values have no character at i[0]. What's the best way to express/evaluate empty values? If it is with '', should I add leading condition in the loop which evaluates value == '', and then 'continue'?
3. Why can I not collapse line 15 into 11 such that I have one statement: `if 'bking' or 'wking' not in board.values():`? If I try that, the statement result is True; however the dictionary contains both values so shouldn't it evaluate to False and keep the code running?

```
def isValidChessBoard(board):
    while True:
        blackPieces = 0
        whitePieces = 0
        wpawn = 0
        bpawn = 0
        letterAxis = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h')
        pieceColour = ('b','w')
        pieceType = ('pawn','knight','bishop','rook','queen','king')

        #one black king and one white king
        if 'bking' not in board.values():
            print('KingError')
            return False
            break
        if 'wking' not in board.values():
            print('KingError')
            return False
            break

        #each player has <= 16 pieces
        for i in board.values():
            if i[0] == 'b':
                blackPieces+=1
            if i[0] == 'w':
                whitePieces+=1
            if whitePieces >= 17:
                print('TotalPieceError')
                return False
                break
            if blackPieces >= 17:
                print('TotalPieceError')
                return False
                break

        #each player has <= 8 pawns
        for i in board.values():
            if i == 'wpawn':
                wpawn+=1
            elif i == 'bpawn':
                bpawn+=1
            if wpawn or bpawn >= 9:
                print('PawnError')
                return False
                break

        #all pieces must be on valid space from '1a' to '8h'
        for i in board.keys():
            if int(i[0]) >= 9:
                print('SpacesError')
                return False
                break
            if i[1] not in letterAxis:
                print('yAxisError')
                return False
                break

        #piece names begin with 'w' or 'b'
        for i in board.values():
            if i[0] not in pieceColour:
                print('WhiteOrBlackError')
                return False
                break

        #piece names must follow with 'pawn', 'knight', 'bishop', 'rook', 'queen', 'king'
        for i in board.values():
            if i[1:] not in pieceType:
                print('PieceTypeError')
                return False
        return 'This board checks out'

board = {'1a': 'bking','2a': 'bqueen','3a': 'brook','4a': 'brook',
'5a': 'bknight','6a': 'bknight','7a':'bbishop','8a': 'bbishop',
'1b': 'bpawn','2b': 'bpawn','3b': 'bpawn','4b':'bpawn',
'5b': 'bpawn','6b': 'bpawn','7b': 'bpawn','8b': 'bpawn',
'1c': 'wking','2c': 'wqueen','3c': 'wrook','4c': 'wrook',
'5c': 'wbishop','6c': 'wbishop','7c': 'wknight','8c':'wknight',
'1e': 'wpawn','2e': 'wpawn','3e': 'wpawn','4e': 'wpawn',
'5e': 'wpawn','6e': 'wpawn','7e': 'wpawn','8e': 'wpawn',
'1f': '','2f': '','3f': '','4f': '','5f': '','6f': '','7f': '','8f': '',
'1g': '','2g': '','3g': '','4g': '','5g': '','6g': '','7g': '','8g': '',
'1h': '','2h': '','3h': '','4h': '','5h': '','6h': '','7h': '','8h': '',}

print(isValidChessBoard(board))

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 23, in isValidChessBoard
    if i[0] == 'b':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Place a conditional after the for loop on line 23, i.e. `if i:` around the other conditionals.  This removes the index out of range error.

Comment: just took a quick look and there is one thing you could delete from you code, the BREAK statement just after the RETURN statement. These are not necessary, if a function reaches a RETURN statement it automatically breaks out so there is no need for BREAK statement.

Comment: Also you can use $$ if 'bking' not in board.values() or 'wking' not in board.values(): $$

Comment: `'bking' or 'wking' not in board.values()` is equivalent to `( 'bking' ) or ( 'wking' not in board.values() )` which always evaluates to just `'bking'` which is true. The correct version would be `'bking' not in board.values() or 'wking' not in board.values()` but a shorter version uses sets: `not {'bking', 'wking'}.issubset(board.values())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: When you define valid count, it doesn't take into consideration that you might get a pawn to the other end of the board and end up with two queens, though I don't know how you could fix this without causing the program to accept wonky answers (such as two queens at the start of a game for instance). Any help here would be appreciated!

Since you asked if there was an alternative I present the following.

**Steps**

- Define the set of all chess pieces
- Define the valid count range of pieces by type
- Count the pieces on the board
- Check pieces counts in a valid range
- Check that positions are valid
- Check that pieces names are valid

**Code**

```
def isValidChessBoard(board):
      """Validate counts and location of pieces on board"""
    
      # Define pieces and colors
      pieces = ['king','queen','rook', 'knight','bishop', 'pawn']
      colors = ['b', 'w']
      # Set of all chess pieces
      all_pieces = set(color+piece for piece in pieces for color in colors)
    
      # Define valid range for count of chess pieces by type (low, high) tuples
      valid_counts = {'king': (1, 1),
                  'queen': (0, 1),
                  'rook': (0, 2),
                  'bishop': (0, 2),
                  'knight': (0, 2),
                  'pawn': (0, 8)}
    
      # Get count of pieces on the board
      piece_cnt = {}
      for v in board.values():
        if v in all_pieces:
          piece_cnt.setdefault(v, 0)
          piece_cnt[v] += 1
    
      # Check if there are a valid number of pieces
      for piece in all_pieces:
        cnt = piece_cnt.get(piece, 0)
        lo, hi = valid_counts[piece[1:]]
        if not lo <= cnt <= hi:   # Count needs to be between lo and hi
          if lo != hi:
            print(f"There should between {lo} and {hi} {piece} but there are {cnt}")
          else:
            print(f"There should be {lo} {piece} but there are {cnt})")
          return False
    
      # Check if locations are valid
      for location in board.keys():
        row = int(location[:1])
        column = location[1:]
        if not ((1 <= row <= 8) and ('a' <= column <= "h")):
          print(f"Invaid to have {board[location]} at postion {location}")
          return False

      # Check if all pieces have valid names
      for loc, piece in board.items():
        if piece:
          if not piece in all_pieces:
            print(f"{piece} is not a valid chess piece at postion {loc}")
            return False

      return True
```

Comment: The only things to compare are: A.  The number of pawns (must be <= 8)  B.  The number of kings  (must be == 2)  C.  The keys in the dictionary   D.  The total number of peices (must be <=16).  This covers every possible chess board and then some that will be limited out by play.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version:

- Remove your `while True:` loop and all your `break`
- Use dictionnary to easier address black and white checks (need no more two if for each color)
- Check position value in the same loop checking piece
- Added a check for only one king of each color
- You can also easily check each piece type count using a dictionnary with piece type as key.

```py
def isValidChessBoard(board):
    piecesCount = {'b': 0, 'w': 0}
    pawnCount = {'b': 0, 'w': 0}
    hasKing = {'b': False, 'w': False}
    letterAxis = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h')
    pieceColour = ('b','w')
    pieceType = ('pawn','knight','bishop','rook','queen','king')

    #each player has <= 16 pieces
    for pos, i in board.items():
        # check position value
        #all pieces must be on valid space from '1a' to '8h'
        if int(pos[0]) >= 9:
            print('SpacesError')
            return False

        if pos[1] not in letterAxis:
            print('yAxisError')
            return False

        # check piece data
        if i != "":
            #piece names begin with 'w' or 'b'
            if i[0] not in pieceColour:
                print('WhiteOrBlackError')
                return False

            thisPieceColour = i[0]
            piecesCount[thisPieceColour] += 1

            if piecesCount[thisPieceColour] >= 17:
                print('TotalPieceError')
                return False

            #piece names must follow with 'pawn', 'knight', 'bishop', 'rook', 'queen', 'king'
            thisPieceType = i[1:]

            if thisPieceType not in pieceType:
                print('PieceTypeError')
                return False

            elif thisPieceType == 'pawn':
                pawnCount[thisPieceColour] += 1

                #each player has <= 8 pawns
                if pawnCount[thisPieceColour] >= 9:
                    print('PawnError')
                    return False

            elif thisPieceType == 'king':
                # one black king and one white king
                if hasKing[thisPieceColour] == True:
                    print("AlreadyHasKingError")

                hasKing[thisPieceColour] = True

    if list(hasKing.values()) != [True, True]:
        print("MissingKingError")
        return False

    return 'This board checks out'

board = {'1a': 'bking','2a': 'bqueen','3a': 'brook','4a': 'brook',
'5a': 'bknight','6a': 'bknight','7a':'bbishop','8a': 'bbishop',
'1b': 'bpawn','2b': 'bpawn','3b': 'bpawn','4b':'bpawn',
'5b': 'bpawn','6b': 'bpawn','7b': 'bpawn','8b': 'bpawn',
'1c': 'wking','2c': 'wqueen','3c': 'wrook','4c': 'wrook',
'5c': 'wbishop','6c': 'wbishop','7c': 'wknight','8c':'wknight',
'1e': 'wpawn','2e': 'wpawn','3e': 'wpawn','4e': 'wpawn',
'5e': 'wpawn','6e': 'wpawn','7e': 'wpawn','8e': 'wpawn',
'1f': '','2f': '','3f': '','4f': '','5f': '','6f': '','7f': '','8f': '',
'1g': '','2g': '','3g': '','4g': '','5g': '','6g': '','7g': '','8g': '',
'1h': '','2h': '','3h': '','4h': '','5h': '','6h': '','7h': '','8h': '',}

print(isValidChessBoard(board))
```

1. See how I refactored the code
2. Just check `if i != ""` before accessing it
3. Well, you can't do it like that because you want to compare two values to several other ones. It is possible, like for example using set.intersection, but seems overkill in your case.

Answer (score 0):

> Promotion in chess is a rule that requires a pawn that reaches the
> eighth rank to be replaced by the player's choice of a bishop, knight,
> rook, or queen of the same color. The piece chosen cannot be another
> king nor another pawn. /Wikipedia

```
board = {'e3': 'wking', 'c6': 'wqueen',
     'g2': 'bbishop', 'd2': 'bqueen', 'g3': 'bking',
     'a1': 'bpawn', 'm1': 'bpawn', 'c1': 'bpawn', 'd1': 'bpawn', 
     'e1': 'bpawn', 'f1': 'bpawn', 'g1': 'bpawn', 'h1': 'bpawn', 
     'e2': 'bpawn', 'a2': 'bpawn'}

def isValidChessBoard(board):
    wKing, bKing, wPieces, bPieces = 0, 0, 0, 0
    wPawns, bPawns, spaces, check = 0, 0, [], True

    for x in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'):
        for y in range(1,9):
            spaces.append(x + str(y))

    for space, piece in board.items():

        if space not in spaces:
            print('Space is wrong: ' + space + ' ' + piece)
            check = False
        if piece == 'wking':
            wKing += 1
        if piece == 'bking':
            bKing += 1
        if piece == 'wpawn':
            wPawns += 1
        if piece == 'bpawn':
            bPawns += 1
        if piece.startswith('w'):
            wPieces += 1
        if piece.startswith('b'):
            bPieces += 1
    if wKing != 1:
        print('White king != 1 : ' + str(wKing))
        check = False
    if bKing != 1:
        print('Black king != 1 : ' + str(bKing))
        check = False
    if wPieces > 16:
        print('Total white pieces on board > 16: ' + str(wPieces))
        check = False
    if bPieces > 16:
        print('Total black pieces on board > 16: ' + str(bPieces))
        check = False
    if wPawns > 8:
        print('White pawns on board > 8: ' + str(wPawns))
        check = False
    if bPawns > 8:
        print('Black pawns on board > 8: ' + str(bPawns))
        check = False
  
    if check:
        return True
    else:
        return False    

print(isValidChessBoard(board))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also learning Python using the same book. I find the exercises to be sometimes a little vague in their requirements definition; that means that some assumptions have to be made.

My assumptions are:

1. The function to be written should only return False or True, not any additionally information regarding why the board doesn't validate.
2. The board verification is "stateless", meaning that the current board definition is checked, and not, for example, if chess rules are followed, etc.
3. Verification of spaces is not required. If a piece is not declared to be in a specific position, that position is empty, i.e. I'm following the rule of "explicit declaration" of the pieces present in the board.

Please, also note that it is not needed to check if the total number of pieces declared for a player/color is more than 16, because if the quantity of each piece is correct, also the total must be correct.

I added comments that should provide enough explanation what each part does, but there are three main sections:

- Constant definitions, to make this code a little more portable.
- Definition of an 'auxiliary' function that check if the quantity of each piece in the board is the one allowed.
- The function requested by the exercise.

The code is also my first attempt to follow PEP 8 recommendations/rules, so any feedback if I'm on the correct way is very welcome, or what is wrong, of course.

I also want to clarify that the code is clearly my creation, but I also tried to pick up some ideas from other contributions/posts/answers; at the end the scope of stackoverflow is to support mutual help and contribution.

The code was tested with some example of boards created for the scope and seems to work properly, but if you spot any error, please let me know in the comments.

Thanks.

PS Edited due to some grammar errors and for better explaining the third assumption.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


# Using lists instead of sets for COLORS and PIECES should work.
#
#
# However, because it is important to stress that those constant define
# a *set* of permitted values, using sets sounds more acceptable.


# Please, note that sets are not explained in the chapter this exercise
# was taken from.

COLORS = {'b', 'w'}

PIECES = {
    'king',
    'queen',
    'rook',
    'bishop',
    'knight',
    'pawn'
    }

VALID_QUANTITY = {
    'king': (1, 1),
    'queen': (0, 1),
    'rook': (0, 2),
    'bishop': (0, 2),
    'knight': (0, 2),
    'pawn': (0, 8),
    }


# The following constants can be easily made using set('12345678') and
# set('abcdefgh').

ROWS = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'}
COLUMNS = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'}


# This function verifies if black pieces or white pieces quantity
# is correct, comparing the total pieces of each kind in the board, with
# the acceptable values defined in VALID_QUANTITY.

def verify_quantity(pieces):
    for piece, quantity in pieces.items():
        low, high = VALID_QUANTITY[piece]
        if low <= quantity <= high:
            return True
        else:
            return False


# This is the main function object of the exercise.

def is_valid_chess_board(board):
    
    black_pieces = {}
    white_pieces = {}
    
    for position, player_piece in board.items():
        
        row, column = position
        player = player_piece[0]
        piece = player_piece[1:]


        # First it is checked that the positions of the pieces, their
        # kind and colors are the ones allowed.
        
        if (row not in ROWS) or (column not in COLUMNS):
            return False
        if player not in COLORS:
            return False
        if piece not in PIECES:
            return False


        # The pieces present in the board are counted for each color.
        
        if player == 'b':
            black_pieces[piece] = black_pieces.get(piece, 0) + 1
        else:
            white_pieces[piece] = white_pieces.get(piece, 0) + 1


        # The quantity is finally checked to see if it is the one
        # allowed by the rules.
        
        if not(verify_quantity(black_pieces) or verify_quantity(white_pieces)):
            return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this. I added criteria for the valid board condition that the book doesn't mention in this question. I check for a valid number of queen, knight, rook, and bishop to make it more accurate to how a chessboard should be.

```
def isValidChessBoard(board: dict) -> bool:
    """Return True or False depending on if  a board is valid in chess."""
    board_pieces = list(board.values()) #initiate variable for repeated use
    all_pieces = ['king', 'queen', 'bishop','knight','rook','pawn']
    blacks, whites = 0, 0 #variable to keep count of black/white pieces
    
    def pCount(to_count: str) -> int:
        """Return count value of the piece"""
        return board_pieces.count(to_count)
        
    #check if board has one king and at most one queen for each side
    if (pCount('bking') != 1) or (pCount('wking') != 1) or \
       (pCount('bqueen') > 1) or (pCount('wqueen') > 1):
        return False  
    
    #check if all pieces names are valid 
    for piece in board_pieces:
        if piece[0] not in 'bw' or piece[1:] not in all_pieces:
            return False
                 
    #check if the position is valid (between 1a and 8h)
    for p in board.keys():
        if p[0] not in '12345678' or p[1] not in 'abcdefgh':
            return False
               
    #check if each side has a valid number of pieces
    for i in board_pieces:
        if i[0] == 'b':
            blacks += 1
        elif i[0] == 'w':
            whites += 1
    
    if (blacks or whites) > 16:
        return False
    elif (pCount('bpawn') or pCount('wpawn')) > 8:
        return False    
    elif (pCount('bbishop') or pCount('bknight') or pCount('brook')) > 2 \
    or   (pCount('wbishop') or pCount('wknight') or pCount('wrook')) > 2:
        return False
            
    return True
```

I do wonder if I could make the count for the rooks, knights, and bishops more efficient as opposed to checking all pieces individually.

To verify the code works as intended I made some test boards, as follow:

```
#more than 2 kings
test_1  = {'1a':'bking', '8f':'wking', '2a': 'bking', '5d':'wking'}

#more than 8 pawns for one side
test_2 = {'2a':'bpawn', '2b': 'bpawn', '2c':'bpawn', '2d': 'bpawn', '2e': 'bpawn',\
         '2f': 'bpawn', '2g': 'bpawn', '2h': 'bpawn',\
         '7a': 'bpawn', '7b': 'wpawn', '8e': 'wking', '1e': 'bking'}

#more than 16 pieces for one player
test_3 = {'2a':'bpawn', '2b': 'bpawn', '2c':'bpawn', '2d': 'bpawn', '2e': 'bpawn',\
         '2f': 'bpawn', '2g': 'bpawn', '2h': 'bpawn',\
         '1a': 'brook', '1b': 'bknight', '1c': 'bbishop', '1d': 'bqueen', \
         '1e':'bking', '1f': 'brook', '1g': 'bknight', '1h': 'bbishop', \
         '3a': 'bpawn', '7b': 'wking', '7c': 'wqueen'}

#invalid space 9d
test_4 = {'1a':'bking', '8f':'wking', '1b':'bqueen', '9d': 'wqueen'}

#names don't begin with 'w' or 'b'
test_5 = {'1a':'bking', '8f':'wking', '1b':'zqueen', '6d': 'wqueen'}

#pieces names 
test_6 = {'1a':'bking', '8f':'wking', '1b':'bqueen', '6d': 'wqueen',\
          '7b':'wknightt'}

#too many white rooks
test_7 = {'1a':'bking', '8f':'wking', '1b':'bqueen', '6d': 'wqueen', \
          '5c': 'wrook', '8c':'wrook', '7d': 'wrook'}

#this board should be valid
test_8 = {'1a':'bking', '8f':'wking', '1b':'bqueen', '6d': 'wqueen', \
          '5c': 'wrook'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach. I decided to compare the proper chess_board with provided test_board.

```py
chess_board = {
    "1a": "wrook", "1b": "wknight", "1c": "wbishop", "1d": "wqueen",
    "1e": "wking", "1f": "wbishop", "1g": "wknight", "1h": "wrook",
    "2a": "wpawn", "2b": "wpawn", "2c": "wpawn", "2d": "wpawn",
    "2e": "wpawn", "2f": "wpawn", "2g": "wpawn", "2h": "wpawn",
    "8a": "brook", "8b": "bknight", "8c": "bbishop", "8d": "bqueen",
    "8e": "bking", "8f": "bbishop", "8g": "bknight", "8h": "brook",
    "7a": "bpawn", "7b": "bpawn", "7c": "bpawn", "7d": "bpawn",
    "7e": "bpawn", "7f": "bpawn", "7g": "bpawn", "7h": "bpawn",    
}
# list keeps broken positions
results_b = []

# TODO: check if figures positions are correct

def isValidChessBoard(board_check):
    for key in board_check:
        if board_check[key] == chess_board[key]:
# this print is just for visualization 
            print(f"{key} has a correct value of {chess_board[key]}")
        if board_check[key] != chess_board[key]:
# this print is just for visualization 
            print(f"{key} has broken value of {chess_board[key]}")
            results_b.append(chess_board[key])
# print broken positions
    for i in results_b:
        print(f"Figure {i} is in a bad position.")


test_board = {
    "1a": "wrook",
    "7h": "wpawn",    
    "7g": "bpawn",
    "1b": "bknight",
}
isValidChessBoard(test_board)
```

Results:

```
1a has a correct value of wrook
7h has broken value of bpawn      
7g has a correct value of bpawn     
1b has broken value of wknight    
Figure bpawn is in a bad position.  
Figure wknight is in a bad position.
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the Chess Dictionary Validator question doesn't require to output the place of the error in the chessboard, so this is my answer:

```
def valid_chess_board(board):
    bpieces, wpieces = 0, 0
    pieces = ("king", "queen", "rook", "bishop", "knight", "pawn")
    board_pieces = list(board.values())

    # Checking the kings
    if board_pieces.count("bking") != 1 or board_pieces.count("wking") != 1:
        return False

    # Checking the pawns
    if board_pieces.count("bpawn") > 8 or board_pieces.count("wpawn") > 8:
        return False

    # Checking the colors
    for p in board_pieces:
        if p[0] == "b" and p[1:] in pieces:
            bpieces += 1
        elif p[0] == "w" and p[1:] in pieces:
            wpieces += 1
        else:
            return False

    # Checking the pieces
    if bpieces > 16 or wpieces > 16:
        return False

    # Checking the spaces
    for s in board:
        if s[0] not in "12345678" or s[1] not in "abcdefgh":
            return False

    return True

chess_board = {
    "1a": "wrook",
    "2a": "wpawn",
    "6a": "bpawn",
    "8a": "brook",
    "2b": "wpawn",
    "5b": "bpawn",
    "1c": "wbishop",
    "2c": "wbishop",
    "3c": "wpawn",
    "6c": "bknight",
    "7c": "bpawn",
    "1d": "wqueen",
    "2d": "wknight",
    "5d": "bpawn",
    "8d": "bqueen",
    "6e": "bbishop",
    "7e": "bbishop",
    "1f": "wrook",
    "2f": "wpawn",
    "3f": "wknight",
    "6f": "bknight",
    "8f": "brook",
    "1g": "wking",
    "2g": "wpawn",
    "7g": "bpawn",
    "8g": "bking",
    "2h": "wpawn",
    "7h": "bpawn",
}

print(valid_chess_board(chess_board))
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution - I used sets to check for valid spaces but this could be achieved with lists as well.

```
board = {'1a': 'wrook', '1b': 'wknight', '1c': 'wbishop', '1d': 'wqueen', '1e': 'wking', '1f': 'wbishop',
'1g': 'wknight', '1h': 'wrook','2a': 'wpawn', '2b': 'wpawn', '2c': 'wpawn', '2d': 'wpawn', '2e': 'wpawn',
'2f': 'wpawn', '2g': 'wpawn', '2h': 'wpawn', '3a': '', '3b': '', '3c': '', '3d': '', '3e': '', '3f': '',
'3g': '', '3h': '', '4a': '', '4b': '', '4c': '', '4d': '', '4e': '', '4f': '', '4g': '', '4h': '',
'5a': '', '5b': '', '5c': '', '5d': '', '5e': '', '5f': '', '5g': '', '5h': '',
'6a': '', '6b': '', '6c': '', '6d': '', '6e': '', '6f': '', '6g': '', '6h': '',
'7a': 'bpawn', '7b': 'bpawn', '7c': 'bpawn', '7d': 'bpawn', '7e': 'bpawn', '7f': 'bpawn', '7g': 'bpawn', '7h': 'bpawn',
'8a': 'brook', '8b': 'bknight', '8c': 'bbishop' , '8d': 'bqueen', '8e': 'bking', '8f': 'bbishop',
'8g': 'bknight','8h': 'brook'}



def isValidChessBoard(board_dict):
    #check for 1 black king and 1 white king
    bking=0
    wking=0
    for king in board_dict.values():
        if king == 'bking':
            bking += 1
        if king == 'wking':
           wking += 1
    if bking != 1 or wking != 1:
        return False

    # check for 8 black pawns and 8 white pawns
    bpawn = 0
    wpawn = 0
    for pawn in board_dict.values():
        if pawn == 'bpawn':
            bpawn += 1
        if pawn == 'wpawn':
            wpawn += 1
    if wpawn != 8 or wpawn != 8:
        return False


    #check for valid spaces
    valid_spaces = {'1a', '1b', '1c', '1d', '1e', '1f', '1g', '1h','2a', '2b', '2c', '2d', '2e', '2f', '2g', '2h',
    '3a', '3b', '3c', '3d', '3e', '3f', '3g', '3h','4a', '4b', '4c', '4d', '4e', '4f', '4g', '4h',
    '5a', '5b', '5c', '5d', '5e', '5f', '5g', '5h','6a', '6b', '6c', '6d', '6e', '6f', '6g', '6h',
    '7a', '7b', '7c', '7d', '7e', '7f', '7g', '7h','8a', '8b', '8c', '8d', '8e', '8f', '8g', '8h'}

    spaces = set()
    for i in board_dict.keys():
        spaces.add(i) # use set add method (like append for lists)
    if spaces != valid_spaces:
        return False


    #check for 16 pieces per player
    piece_count = 0
    for piece in board_dict.values():
        if piece != '': # don't count the empty spaces (no pieces)
            piece_count += 1
    if piece_count != 32: # 16 x 2 = 32 total pieces
        return False

    return 'This is a valid board'


print(isValidChessBoard(board))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my attempt.
I would love to get some feedback from more experienced people.

```
board_width = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
board_height = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
board = []
for x in board_width:  #create a list of possible board positions
    for y in board_height:
        board.append(x + y)



pieces = ['king', 'queen', 'rook', 'rook',
          'bishop', 'bishop', 'knight', 'knight',
          'pawn', 'pawn', 'pawn', 'pawn', 'pawn',
          'pawn', 'pawn', 'pawn']    #list of all pieces for each player

white_pieces = pieces.copy()
black_pieces = pieces.copy()

def is_valid_chess_board(chess_dict):

    if 'wking' and 'bking' in chess_dict.values():

        for key, value in chess_dict.items(): #iterate each dict elements

            if value == '':
                board.remove(key)

            elif value.startswith('w') and key in board:  
                lis_val = list(value)
                lis_val.remove('w')
                val_str = "".join(lis_val)
                if val_str in white_pieces:
                    white_pieces.remove(val_str)
                    board.remove(key)
                    print(f"The White {val_str} was placed at {key}")
                else:
                    print(f"This {val_str} is not a proper Chess piece")

            elif value.startswith('b') and key in board:
                lis_val = list(value)
                lis_val.remove('b')
                val_str = "".join(lis_val)
                if val_str in black_pieces:
                    black_pieces.remove(val_str)
                    board.remove(key)
                    print(f"The Black {val_str} was placed at {key}")
                else:
                    print(f"This {val_str} is not a proper Chess piece")

            else:
                print("You have an incomplete Chess board")
                break
    else:
        print("You have an incomplete Chess board!")

    print(board)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is not an answer to the question. The OP didn't ask for other versions. They were asking for advice on specific parts of their version. Start a new question with specific points if you want to have other people look at your version. Or try it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -1):

```
def isValid(board):
    # PUT TOGETHER A LIST OF ALL POSSIBLE PIECES
    pieces = ['king', 'queen', 'rook', 'knight', 'bishop', 'pawn']
    colors = ['b', 'w']
    all_pieces = {}
    possible_pieces = ['']
    color_count = {'b': 0, 'w': 0}
    for piece in pieces:
        for color in colors:
            possible_pieces.append('{}{}'.format(color, piece))
            all_pieces.setdefault('{}{}'.format(color, piece), 0)

    # CHECKS IF PIECES HAVE VALID NAMES
    for v in board.values():
        if v not in possible_pieces:
            print('Error: Invalid chess piece type')
            return False

    # ITERATE THROUGH BOARD, AND COUNT PIECES AND COLORS
    for k in board:
        if board.get(k) == '':
            continue
        all_pieces[board.get(k)] += 1      # INCREASE PIECE TYPE
        color_count[board.get(k)[0]] += 1  # INCREASE COLOR COUNT

    # CHECK TOTAL WHITE/BLACK PIECES
    if color_count['w'] > 16 or color_count['b'] > 16:
        print('Error: Invalid number of white or black pieces')
        return False

    # CHECKS IF VALID NUMBER OF PIECES
    for i in possible_pieces:
        num = all_pieces.get(i)
        if i == 'bking' or i == 'wking':
            if num != 1:
                print('Error: Invalid number of Kings')
                return False
        elif i == 'bqueen' or i == 'wqueen':
            if num > 1:
                print('Error: Invalid number of Queens')
                return False
        elif i == 'brook' or i == 'wrook':
            if num > 2:
                print('Error: Invalid number of Rooks')
                return False
        elif i == 'bknight' or i == 'wknight':
            if num > 2:
                print('Error: Invalid number of Knights')
                return False
        elif i == 'bbishop' or i == 'wbishop':
            if num > 2:
                print('Error: Invalid number of Bishops')
                return False
        elif i == 'bpawn' or i == 'wpawn':
            if num > 8:
                print('Error: Invalid number of Pawns')
                return False

    # CHECK ALL VALID SPACES
    for s in board:
        if s[0] not in '12345678' or s[1] not in 'abcdefgh':
            print('Error: Space is not valid!')
            return False

    # IF PASS ALL CHECKS, THE BOARD IS VALID 
    return True
```

Answer (score -1):

You guys are not following the book. You guys are writing codes that would confuse even the greatest expert or even the author himself. All the hints to write this code is in the book. This means you guys didn't read the book. If you read it, you wouldn't be making all these mistakes in your code. Please find the final answer below, it's simple and efficient and better than all the code you guys posted in this thread:

```
def isValidChessBoard(board):
    board = {'1a': 'brook', '1b': 'bknight', '1c': 'bbishop', '1d': 'bking', '1e': 'bqueen', '1f': 'bbishop',
             '1g': 'bknight', '1h': 'brook',
             '2a': 'bpawn', '2b': 'bpawn', '2c': 'bpawn', '2d': 'bpawn', '2e': 'bpawn', '2f': 'bpawn',
             '2g': 'bpawn', '2h': 'bpawn',
             '3a': '', '3b': '', '3c': '', '3d': '', '3e': '', '3f': '',
             '3g': '', '3h': '',
             '4a': '', '4b': '', '4c': '', '4d': '', '4e': '', '4f': '',
             '4g': '', '4h': '',
             '5a': '', '5b': '', '5c': '', '5d': '', '5e': '', '5f': '',
             '5g': '', '5h': '',
             '6a': '', '6b': '', '6c': '', '6d': '', '6e': '', '6f': '',
             '6g': '', '6h': '',
             '7a': 'wpawn', '7b': 'wpawn', '7c': 'wpawn', '7d': 'wpawn', '7e': 'wpawn', '7f': 'wpawn',
             '7g': 'wpawn', '7h': 'wpawn',
             '8a': 'wrook', '8b': 'wknight', '8c': 'wbishop', '8d': 'wking', '8e': 'wqueen', '8f': 'wbishop',
             '8g': 'wknight', '8h': 'wrook'
             }
    # Criteria 1 - 1 bbking and 1 wking

    count = {}

    for v in board.values():
        count.setdefault(v, 0)
        count[v] = count[v] + 1
    # print(count)
    # Criteria 2 - Each player can have at most 16 pieces, at most 8 pawns

    del count['']
    #print(count)
    pieces = 0
    for v in count.values():
        pieces = pieces + v
    #print(pieces)

    # Criteria 3 - All pieces must be on a valid space '1a' to '8h', not '9z'

    validSpace = {'1a': 'brook', '1b': 'bknight', '1c': 'bbishop', '1d': 'bking', '1e': 'bqueen', '1f': 'bbishop',
             '1g': 'bknight', '1h': 'brook',
             '2a': 'bpawn', '2b': 'bpawn', '2c': 'bpawn', '2d': 'bpawn', '2e': 'bpawn', '2f': 'bpawn',
             '2g': 'bpawn', '2h': 'bpawn',
             '3a': '', '3b': '', '3c': '', '3d': '', '3e': '', '3f': '',
             '3g': '', '3h': '',
             '4a': '', '4b': '', '4c': '', '4d': '', '4e': '', '4f': '',
             '4g': '', '4h': '',
             '5a': '', '5b': '', '5c': '', '5d': '', '5e': '', '5f': '',
             '5g': '', '5h': '',
             '6a': '', '6b': '', '6c': '', '6d': '', '6e': '', '6f': '',
             '6g': '', '6h': '',
             '7a': 'wpawn', '7b': 'wpawn', '7c': 'wpawn', '7d': 'wpawn', '7e': 'wpawn', '7f': 'wpawn',
             '7g': 'wpawn', '7h': 'wpawn',
             '8a': 'wrook', '8b': 'wknight', '8c': 'wbishop', '8d': 'wking', '8e': 'wqueen', '8f': 'wbishop',
             '8g': 'wknight', '8h': 'wrook'
             }

    if count['bking'] == 1:
        if count['wking'] == 1:
            if pieces == 32:
                if count['bpawn'] == 8:
                    if count['wpawn'] == 8:
                        if board == validSpace:
                            #return 'True: This is a Vaild Chessboard'
                            return True



chessBoardOne = {'1a': 'wrook', '1b': 'wknight', '1c': 'wbishop', '1d': 'wqueen', '1e': 'wking', '1f': 'wbishop',
'1g': 'wknight', '1h': 'wrook','2a': 'wpawn', '2b': 'wpawn', '2c': 'wpawn', '2d': 'wpawn', '2e': 'wpawn',
'2f': 'wpawn', '2g': 'wpawn', '2h': 'wpawn', '3a': '', '3b': '', '3c': '', '3d': '', '3e': '', '3f': '',
'3g': '', '3h': '', '4a': '', '4b': '', '4c': '', '4d': '', '4e': '', '4f': '', '4g': '', '4h': '',
'5a': '', '5b': '', '5c': '', '5d': '', '5e': '', '5f': '', '5g': '', '5h': '',
'6a': '', '6b': '', '6c': '', '6d': '', '6e': '', '6f': '', '6g': '', '6h': '',
'7a': 'bpawn', '7b': 'bpawn', '7c': 'bpawn', '7d': 'bpawn', '7e': 'bpawn', '7f': 'bpawn', '7g': 'bpawn', '7h': 'bpawn',
'8a': 'brook', '8b': 'bknight', '8c': 'bbishop' , '8d': 'bqueen', '8e': 'bking', '8f': 'bbishop',
'8g': 'bknight','8h': 'brook'}

print(isValidChessBoard(chessBoardOne))
#print(Answer)
```

Comment: Please if you want the code, hit me up and i will send it to you. This thread didn't format my code properly.

Comment: Do not use this Code. I found out there is a bug in my code. Honestly, I didn't test it out with a wrong chessboard initially. Now that I have, I noticed it was returned true even if you had nine pawns instead of 8. Sorry, All.

Answer (score -1):

def isValidChessBoard(board):
board = {'1a': board['1a'], '1b': board['1b']  , '1c': board['1c'], '1d': board['1d'], '1e': board['1e'], '1f': board['1f'],
'1g': board['1g'], '1h': board['1h'],
'2a': board['2a'], '2b': board['2b'], '2c': board['2c'], '2d': board['2d'], '2e': board['2e'], '2f': board['2f'],
'2g': board['2g'], '2h': board['2h'],
'3a': board['3a'], '3b': board['3b'], '3c': board['3c'], '3d': board['3d'], '3e': board['3e'], '3f': board['3f'],
'3g': board['3g'], '3h': board['3h'],
'4a': board['4a'], '4b': board['4b'], '4c': board['4c'], '4d': board['4d'], '4e': board['4e'], '4f': board['4f'],
'4g': board['4g'], '4h': board['4h'],
'5a': board['5a'], '5b': board['5b'], '5c': board['5c'], '5d': board['5d'], '5e': board['5e'], '5f': board['5f'],
'5g': board['5g'], '5h': board['5h'],
'6a': board['6a'], '6b': board['6b'], '6c': board['6c'], '6d': board['6d'], '6e': board['6e'], '6f': board['6f'],
'6g': board['6g'], '6h': board['6h'],
'7a': board['7a'], '7b': board['7b'], '7c': board['7c'], '7d': board['7d'], '7e': board['7e'], '7f': board['7f'],
'7g': board['7g'], '7h': board['7h'],
'8a': board['8a'], '8b': board['8b'], '8c': board['8c'], '8d': board['8d'], '8e': board['8e'], '8f': board['8f'],
'8g': board['8g'], '8h': board['8h']}
# Criteria 1 - 1 bbking and 1 wking

```
count = {}

for v in board.values():
    count.setdefault(v, 0)
    count[v] = count[v] + 1
print(count)
# Criteria 2 - Each player can have at most 16 pieces, at most 8 pawns

del count['']
#print(count)
pieces = 0
for v in count.values():
    pieces = pieces + v
#print(pieces)

# Criteria 3 and 4 - All pieces must be on a valid space '1a' to '8h', not '9z'. Names must start with w or b.

validSpace = {'1a': 'brook', '1b': 'bknight', '1c': 'bbishop', '1d': 'bking', '1e': 'bqueen', '1f': 'bbishop',
         '1g': 'bknight', '1h': 'brook',
         '2a': 'bpawn', '2b': 'bpawn', '2c': 'bpawn', '2d': 'bpawn', '2e': 'bpawn', '2f': 'bpawn',
         '2g': 'bpawn', '2h': 'bpawn',
         '3a': '', '3b': '', '3c': '', '3d': '', '3e': '', '3f': '',
         '3g': '', '3h': '',
         '4a': '', '4b': '', '4c': '', '4d': '', '4e': '', '4f': '',
         '4g': '', '4h': '',
         '5a': '', '5b': '', '5c': '', '5d': '', '5e': '', '5f': '',
         '5g': '', '5h': '',
         '6a': '', '6b': '', '6c': '', '6d': '', '6e': '', '6f': '',
         '6g': '', '6h': '',
         '7a': 'wpawn', '7b': 'wpawn', '7c': 'wpawn', '7d': 'wpawn', '7e': 'wpawn', '7f': 'wpawn',
         '7g': 'wpawn', '7h': 'wpawn',
         '8a': 'wrook', '8b': 'wknight', '8c': 'wbishop', '8d': 'wking', '8e': 'wqueen', '8f': 'wbishop',
         '8g': 'wknight', '8h': 'wrook'
         }
print(count['bking'])
print(count['bpawn'])
if count['bking'] == 1:
    if count['wking'] == 1:
        if pieces == 32:
            if count['bpawn'] == 8:
                if count['wpawn'] == 8:
                    if board == validSpace:
                        return True
```

chessBoardOne = {'1a': 'brook', '1b': 'bknight', '1c': 'bbishop', '1d': 'bking', '1e': 'bqueen', '1f': 'bbishop',
'1g': 'bknight', '1h': 'brook',
'2a': 'bpawn', '2b': 'bpawn', '2c': 'bpawn', '2d': 'bpawn', '2e': 'bpawn', '2f': 'bpawn',
'2g': 'bpawn', '2h': 'bpawn',
'3a': '', '3b': '', '3c': '', '3d': '', '3e': '', '3f': '',
'3g': '', '3h': '',
'4a': '', '4b': '', '4c': '', '4d': '', '4e': '', '4f': '',
'4g': '', '4h': '',
'5a': '', '5b': '', '5c': '', '5d': '', '5e': '', '5f': '',
'5g': '', '5h': '',
'6a': '', '6b': '', '6c': '', '6d': '', '6e': '', '6f': '',
'6g': '', '6h': '',
'7a': 'wpawn', '7b': 'wpawn', '7c': 'wpawn', '7d': 'wpawn', '7e': 'wpawn', '7f': 'wpawn',
'7g': 'wpawn', '7h': 'wpawn',
'8a': 'wrook', '8b': 'wknight', '8c': 'wbishop', '8d': 'wking', '8e': 'wqueen', '8f': 'wbishop',
'8g': 'wknight', '8h': 'wrook'
}

print(isValidChessBoard(chessBoardOne))
#print(Answer)

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28220065)

Comment: @Adam, My code is cut into three sections. Any hints on how to get my code formatted correctly?

Answer (score -1):

```
piece = {}


# enter chess piece and position
def pieceSet():
    while True:
        print("Enter chess piece: (start with 'b' or 'w' + piece) or  enter 'q' to exit")
        pc = str(input())
        if pc == 'q':
            break
        print("Place the piece on the chess board: ")
        position = str(input())
        piece[str(position)] = str(pc)


def isValidChessBoard():
    # board position and coordinates
    board = []
    for row in range(1, 9):
        for col in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'):
            board.append(str(row)+str(col))

    # check if both kings are still on the board
    if 'wking' not in piece.values() or 'bking' not in piece.values():
        print('---The Board is Invalid!---')
        print("King is not on the board!")
        return False

    # check the position of every piece on the board
    for key in piece.keys():
        if key not in board:
            print('---The Board is Invalid!---')
            print("Chess Board only has 8 boxes per row ('a' to 'h') and 8 boxes percolumn ('1 to 8')")
            return False

    # check if the name starts with a "w" or "b"
    for pieces in piece.values():
        if pieces[0] != "b" and pieces[0] != "w":
            print('---The Board is Invalid!---')
            print("Chess pieces only have 2 colors: (b)lack and (w)hite")
            return False

    # check the quantity of every chess pieces and see if every piece is valid
    bpawn = 0
    wpawn = 0
    bking = 0
    wking = 0
    bqueen = 0
    wqueen = 0
    bbishop = 0
    wbishop = 0
    bknight = 0
    wknight = 0
    brook = 0
    wrook = 0
    for value in piece.values():
        if value == 'bpawn':
            bpawn += 1
            if bpawn > 8:
                print('---The Board is Invalid!---')
                print("Exceeded the limit of bpawn!")
                return False
            else:
                continue
        elif value == 'wpawn':
            wpawn += 1
            if wpawn > 8:
                print('---The Board is Invalid!---')
                print("Exceeded the limit of wpawn!")
                return False
            else:
                continue
        elif value == 'bking':
            bking += 1
            if bking > 1:
                print('---The Board is Invalid!---')
                print("Exceeded the limit of bking!")
                return False
            else:
                continue
        elif value == 'wking':
            wking += 1
            if wking > 1:
                print('---The Board is Invalid!---')
                print("Exceeded the limit of wking!")
                return False
            else:
                continue
        elif value == 'bqueen':
            bqueen += 1
            if bqueen > 1:
                print('---The Board is Invalid!---')
                print("Exceeded the limit of bqueen!")
                return False
            else:
                continue
        elif value == 'wqueen':
            wqueen += 1
            if wqueen > 1:
                print('---The Board is Invalid!---')
                print("Exceeded the limit of wqueen!")
                return False
            else:
                continue
        elif value == 'bbishop':
            bbishop += 1
            if bbishop > 2:
                print('---The Board is Invalid!---')
                print("Exceeded the limit of bbishop!")
                return False
            else:
                continue
        elif value == 'wbishop':
            wbishop += 1
            if wbishop > 2:
                print('---The Board is Invalid!---')
                print("Exceeded the limit of wbishop!")
                return False
            else:
                continue
        elif value == 'bknight':
            bknight += 1
            if bknight > 2:
                print('---The Board is Invalid!---')
                print("Exceeded the limit of bknight!")
                return False
            else:
                continue
        elif value == 'wknight':
            wknight += 1
            if wknight > 2:
                print('---The Board is Invalid!---')
                print("Exceeded the limit of wknight!")
                return False
            else:
                continue
        elif value == 'brook':
            brook += 1
            if brook > 2:
                print('---The Board is Invalid!---')
                print("Exceeded the limit of brook!")
                return False
            else:
                continue
        elif value == 'wrook':
            wrook += 1
            if wrook > 2:
                print('---The Board is Invalid!---')
                print("Exceeded the limit of wrook!")
                return False
            else:
                continue
        else:
            print('---The Board is Invalid!---')
            print(str(value) + " piece not included!")
            return False


def result():
    if isValidChessBoard() == False:
        return False
    else:
        print('---The Board is Valid!---')
        return True


pieceSet()
print('piece =', piece)
print(result())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#validate chess board 
dict_chess ={'1a':'bking', '8f':'wking', '1b':'bqueen', '6d': 'wqueen', \
          '5c': 'wrook'}


chessHeightLocation = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
chessWidthLocation = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
colors = ['w', 'b']
pieces = ['pawn', 'knight', 'bishop', 'rook', 'queen', 'king']
def isValidChessBoard(dictChess):
    playerCount = {'bpawn': 0, 'wpawn': 0, 'wking': 0, 'bking': 0, 'wpieceCount': 0, 'bpieceCount': 0}
    for keysInChessBoard in dictChess:
        #check for Space
        #print(int(keysInChessBoard[0]) not in chessWidthLocation)
        if (int(keysInChessBoard[0]) not in chessWidthLocation) or (keysInChessBoard[1] not in chessHeightLocation):
            print('Not valid space: ' + keysInChessBoard)
            return False
        
        #check for black and white
        if dictChess[keysInChessBoard][0] not in colors:
            print('Not valid color of piece should have b for black or w for white: ' + dictChess[keysInChessBoard])
            return False
        
        #check for piece
        if dictChess[keysInChessBoard][1:] not in pieces:
            print('Not valid piece: ' + dictChess[keysInChessBoard])
            return False
        
        #check for pawns
        if dictChess[keysInChessBoard] == 'bpawn' or dictChess[keysInChessBoard] == 'wpawn':
            playerCount[dictChess[keysInChessBoard]] += 1
            if playerCount[dictChess[keysInChessBoard]] > 8:
                print('More than 8 pawns in one player')
                return False
        
        #check for king
        if dictChess[keysInChessBoard] == 'bking' or dictChess[keysInChessBoard] == 'wking':
            playerCount[dictChess[keysInChessBoard]] += 1
            if playerCount[dictChess[keysInChessBoard]] > 1:
                print('More than 1 king')
                return False
        #pieceCount
        if dictChess[keysInChessBoard][0] in colors:
            if dictChess[keysInChessBoard][0] == 'w':
                playerCount[dictChess[keysInChessBoard][0]+'pieceCount'] += 1
            elif dictChess[keysInChessBoard][0] == 'b':
                playerCount[dictChess[keysInChessBoard][0]+'pieceCount'] += 1
            if playerCount[dictChess[keysInChessBoard][0]+'pieceCount'] > 16:
                print('More than 16 piece')
                return False
        #print(playerCount)
   return True
print(isValidChessBoard(dict_chess))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

just another option

````
```
chessboard = {'1a': 'bking', '2a': 'bqueen', '3a': 'brook', '4a': 'brook',
              '5a': 'bknight', '6a': 'bknight', '7a': 'bbishop', '8a': 'bbishop',
              '1b': 'bpawn', '2b': 'bpawn', '3b': 'bpawn', '4b': 'bpawn',
              '5b': 'bpawn', '6b': 'bpawn', '7b': 'bpawn', '8b': 'bpawn',
              '1c': 'wking', '2c': 'wqueen', '3c': 'wrook', '4c': 'wrook',
              '5c': 'wbishop', '6c': 'wbishop', '7c': 'wknight', '8c': 'wknight',
              '1e': 'wpawn', '2e': 'wpawn', '3e': 'wpawn', '4e': 'wpawn',
              '5e': 'wpawn', '6e': 'wpawn', '7e': 'wpawn', '8e': 'wpawn',
              '1f': '', '2f': '', '3f': '', '4f': '', '5f': '', '6f': '', '7f': '', '8f': '',
              '1g': '', '2g': '', '3g': '', '4g': '', '5g': '', '6g': '', '7g': '', '8g': '',
              '1h': '', '2h': '', '3h': '', '4h': '', '5h': '', '6h': '', '7h': '', '8h': '', }


def check_location(board):
    for location in board.keys():
        row = int(location[:1])
        column = location[1:]
        if not ((1 <= row <= 8) and ('a' <= column <= "h")):
            print(f"Invalid to have {board[location]} at postion {location}")
            return False


def check_piece_count(board):
    pieces = ['wpawn', 'bpawn', 'wknight', 'bknight', 'bbishop',
              'wbishop', 'wrook', 'brook', 'wqueen', 'bqueen', 'wking', 'bking']
    max_pieces = [8, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]

    for piece in zip(pieces, max_pieces, board.keys()):
        if sum(value == piece[0] for value in board.values()) > piece[1]:
            return False
    return True


if check_location(chessboard) == None and check_piece_count(chessboard) == True:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
````